# Anyway to "reset" styles?

Tags: css

An existing style sheet has a whole bevy of styles defined for the A element strewn all over the place.  I find it pretty difficult to track and trace everything.

I then have:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>xxxxx</li>
     <li><a href='...'>yyyyy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't want the A element above to inherit what are in the style sheet.  I also do not want to remove the classes for the UL element as there are other side effects.  I know I can override the A styles by specifically setting inline styles, but that would be a lot to override. Is there a way to make that A element discard what is defined for A and have every style at its default?

Comment: Can't be done. You have to inline `style` it. Or basically the same thing as inlining it... assign an `id="yourId"` so you can use a css stylesheet.  Either way you basically have to single it out.

Comment: how about giving your specific a element an id, and use some selector like :  **ul li a#AsID**, which should select the a tag (and then use a [reset css](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)) for your a tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't...

Have you thought about javaScript? You could create a snippet that works like this:

```
function resetCss(element) {
  element.style.color = '#000000';
  element.style.textDecoration = 'none';
  // ...
}

function reset() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for (element in elements) {
    if (element.className == 'reset') {
      resetCss(element); // This function is called on every tag with the reset class.
    }
  }
}
```

Call `reset()` when the DOM is ready and give the class `reset` to all your to-be-reset elements. Example: `<a href="#" class="reset">Link</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible I'm afraid (with standard CSS anyway, maybe with a precompiled like LESS). The "normal way" here is to add an identifier to  and make a #mylist a { }. You would then have to change each attribute you don't like.

Of course the best thing would be to start over and make the CSS less of a living hell :)

Comment: Thanks, but I am building on top of the standard MVC template in VS2013.  Hate to tear it apart but also hate that it's utterly confusing and time sucking.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility that you can try. It way can rewrite (overload) styles every that you need. Use strict selecting via ">" selector in styles from you body element to you target 'a' (It's important write strict rules from body, but in several case don't need). And place this overloads style after all - rule for overloads styles - should be placed after all or last included. I use this method every day and with bootstrap, select2, foundation, and other libs, i just overwrite styles.

Example (Just consider that you html example placed in "body" and "header" elements):

body > header > .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > a { /* You styles that overload all previous for this element */}